# How can I shorten this program using Luhn's algorithm to check credit card number?

Tags: python-3.x

```
import math
 
def luhns_algorithm(num):
    
    argument_is_integer = isinstance(num, int)
    
    number = num #from this number we will get every other digit
        
    every_other_digit = [] #we will append every other digit to this list
    
    not_every_other_digit = [] #we will append the other digits to this list
    
    every_other_digit_times_two = [] #we will append every other digit multiplied by two to this list
    
    sum_of_digits_in_every_other_digit = 0 #Counter to store the sum of the digits of the numbers in the list 
                                                  #every_other_digit_times_two
                                                  
    valid = False #The default is that the credit card is not valid. If the last digit of the target sum is 0, the card is valid
    
    rem = 1 #We will use rem in the while loop to get the last digits of the number
    
    target_sum = 0
    
    
    
    #Checks that the argument is an integer. If not, the credit card number is not valid. 
        
    if argument_is_integer != True:
        
        
        return
    
    
    else:
    
        #In the following while loop, the goal is to split the digits of the number in two halves and store those 
        #halves in two separate lists
        
        while number > 1: #We will divide the number until it is less than zero, which means there are no more digits
            
            rem = number % 10 
            
            not_every_other_digit.append(rem)
            
            number /= 10 
            
            number = math.floor(number)
            
            rem = number % 10 
            
            every_other_digit.append(rem) 
            
            number /= 10 
            
            number = math.floor(number)
        
        
        #In this for loop we iterate through the digits in every_other_digits and appends those
        #digits multiplied by two to a new list
        
        for digit in every_other_digit: 
        
            every_other_digit_times_two.append(digit * 2)
        
        #Because we are supposed to add only the digits of the products of every other digit times two, we must create
        #two conditionals. The first if- statement is for digits from 0-9. The else- statement is for numbers > 10, 
        #where we must first split the number into two digits and then sum those digits to sum_of_digits_every_other_digit_times_two
        
        for digit in every_other_digit_times_two:
            
            if digit < 10:
                sum_of_digits_in_every_other_digit += digit
        
            else:
                second_digit = digit % 10 
                first_digit = math.floor(digit / 10)
                sum_of_digits_in_every_other_digit += first_digit
                sum_of_digits_in_every_other_digit += second_digit
        
        #Creates empty counter so that we can add the digits not multiplied by two
        sum_of_digits_not_multiplied_by_two = 0
        
        #Iterates through digits in the half that is not multiplied by two, and adds them to counter
        
        for digit in not_every_other_digit:
            sum_of_digits_not_multiplied_by_two += digit
        
        #Finally we can get the target sum, which is the sum of the two counters we have made above
        
        target_sum = sum_of_digits_in_every_other_digit + sum_of_digits_not_multiplied_by_two
        
        #If last digit of target sum is 0, the credit card number is legit
        
    if target_sum % 10 == 0:
        valid = True
        
        
        
    return valid
            
    #In this function we will determine which company has issued the credit card, and use our function luhns_algorithm to
    #check if the credit card number is valid
    
def credit_card(num):
    
    digits = 0
    company = ""
    number = num
    
    
    
    valid = luhns_algorithm(num)
    
    if valid == True:
    
        while number > 1:
            digits += 1
            number /= 10
        
        first_two_digits = num / 10 ** (digits - 2)
        first_two_digits = math.floor(first_two_digits)
        first_digit = first_two_digits / 10
            
        if digits == 15:
            if first_two_digits == 34 or first_two_digits == 37:
                company = "AMEX"
        
        elif digits == 13:
            company = "VISA"
        
        elif digits == 16 and first_digit == 4:
            company = "VISA"
        
        elif digits == 16 and 51 <= first_two_digits <= 55:
            company = "MasterCard"
        
        
    
    else:
        
        return print("The credit card number is invalid.")
    
    return print("The credit card is issued by " + company)

credit_card(4003600000000014)

#Output = The credit card is issued by VISA
```

Comment: There is a lot of redundant comments and blank lines. I would start there.

Answer (score 1):

There's a tonne of intermediate variables that don't need to exist, as well as insisting that the credit card number be treated as an integer when a string is probably easier.

Also, don't bake printing into your functions, and don't require that the company determination logic operate on a valid card. Add type hints, and this brings you to

```
from typing import Optional


def is_card_valid(num: str) -> bool:
    if not num.isdigit():
        return False

    total = sum(
        int(num[i])
        for i in range(1, len(num), 2)
    )

    for i in range(0, len(num), 2):
        d1, d2 = divmod(2*int(num[i]), 10)
        total += d1 + d2

    return total % 10 == 0


def get_card_company(num: str) -> Optional[str]:
    digits = len(num)

    if digits == 15:
        if num[:2] in {'34', '37'}:
            return 'AMEX'
        if num[:2] == '13':
            return 'VISA'

    elif digits == 16:
        if num[0] == '4':
            return 'VISA'
        if num[0] == '5' and num[1] in '12345':
            return 'MasterCard'


card = '4003600000000014'
if is_card_valid(card):
    print('Card is valid')
    print('The credit card is issued by', get_card_company(card))
else:
    print('Card is invalid')
```